# Bidirectional reference does not work Symfony2

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, database

I'm using Sonata Admin Bundle to create the back-end, But I have a problem with One-to-Many : 
I have "Question" document which references one "QuizzPart":

```
/**
*@MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="QuizzPart", inversedBy="questions") 
*/
protected $quizzPart ;
```

And the "QuizzPart" document references many questions :

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Question",  mappedBy="quizzpart", cascade="all")
 */
protected $questions = array();
```

and this is how I add a QuizzPart to the Question With sonata admin :

```
$formMapper->add('quizzPart', 'sonata_type_model', array('by_reference' => true,
'required' => false)) ;
```

But when I add a Question and I set its QuizzPart there is no reference of the Question in the Quizzpart:
This is the QuizzPart setter method :

```
public function setQuizzPart(\ATS\QuizzBundle\Document\QuizzPart $quizzPart)
  {

    $this->quizzPart = $quizzPart;
    $quizzPart->addQuestion($this);

    return $this;
  }
```

The question is not added to the QuizzPart object, Any one can help ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way quizz parts are added to your question entity. It should look like this:

```
public function addQuizzPart(QuizzPart $quizzPart)
{
    $this->quizzParts->add($quizzPart);
    $quizzPart->setQuestion($this); //This way the entities are "connected"        

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm Doing @Stiven, but it the Object QuizzPart is not updated in the data Base

Comment: it seems like the flush() opération for the quizzPart is not executed

Comment: try making your `by_reference => false`. Your question entity is trying to use `setQuizzPart` instead of `addQuizzPart`

Comment: A question references only one quizzPart so there is no addQuizzPart ! it is a setQuizzPart

Comment: form option `by_reference` has little to do with object references. Have a look at  [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference)

Comment: I tried with the two cases "by_reference" => true or false, and it is always the same issue